# Maximum files in a single FAT32 directory?

Tags: fat32

This is more of a curiousity thing, but recently I had errors when copying files to my thumb drive because I had reached some file limit.

What exactly is this limit?

Comment: `I had reached some file limit`, Don't you think it could help if you could tell the exact error message?

Comment: Why don't you look at the FAT32 specification? It lists all those details.

Comment: If you have 65k files in a single folder you have a problem.  You unliikely have 268 million files on the disk, if you do, get rid of some of the files.

Answer (score 6):

For FAT32, maximum number of files in a single folder is **65,534**.

Additional info for FAT32:

- Maximum disk size:  **2 TB**
- Maximum file size:  **4 GB**
- Maximum number of files on disk:  **268,435,437**